# How do I find TFS builds by controller used to build it?

Tags: tfs

Here is my code:

```
var tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(TFS_SERVER_URL));
tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();

var buildServer = (IBuildServer)tfs.GetService(typeof(IBuildServer));
var spec = buildServer.CreateBuildDetailSpec(projectName);
spec.QueryOrder = BuildQueryOrder.FinishTimeDescending;
spec.MinFinishTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(minFinishTimeOfs);
spec.MaxFinishTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(maxFinishTimeOfs);
if (reason != null)
{
    spec.Reason = reason.Value;
}
var buildDetails = buildServer.QueryBuilds(spec).Builds;
```

As you can see, I know how to query by time and build reason. But I want to be able to query by the build controller and I do not see how to do it efficiently. The inefficient way is to get the builds across all the build controllers and then filter them out, but I would like to avoid fetching irrelevant build details in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API to judge from build definition to get IBuildDetail builds. As you mentioned above, you have to get firstly get all builds, and filter out unwanted builds with the [IBuildDetail.BuildControllerUri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.client.ibuilddetail.buildcontrolleruri(v=vs.120).aspx) property.